# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted even though the csrf token is present

Tags: django, web, csrf, django-csrf

I am making a project in Django for an NGO. I keep running in the csrf toke missing error.
I have the `{% csrf_token %}` tag in the form tags. The csrf is working on other forms but isn't working on this form only.

[image]

here is the html page that is resulting in this error:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Assistanza</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous" />



</head>

<body>
    <!--NavBar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static 'main/images/navbarlogo.jpg' %}" alt="Logo" width="80"
                    height="40" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" /></a>
            <div class="container marketing">
                <div id=timer></div>
            </div><br><br><br>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div><br><br></div>
    <script>
        var timeLimit = {{ time_limit }};
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            var minutes = Math.floor(timeLimit / 60);
            var seconds = timeLimit % 60;

            // Display time in minutes and seconds
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
                'Time Left: ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's';

            // Check if time is up
            if (timeLimit <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                // Redirect to the completion page
                window.location.replace("{% url 'test_complete' %}");
            }

            timeLimit--;
        }, 1000); // Update every 1 second
    </script>

    <div class="container marketing">
        <form class="form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return saveAns()" action="{% url 'test_complete' %}"
            method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for q in questions %}


            <h3 class="text-primary">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{q.question}}</h3>
            <!-- 
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
                value="C24rUotmdHawVQJL3KrqiWxvti8UffOFYUc8TRbZtLt36AVLdP3jbkzUVe3beRAa"> -->


            <div class="form-check mx-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ q.course }} {{forloop.counter}}"
                    id="{{q.option1}}" value="Option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="option1">
                    {{q.option1}}
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="form-check mx-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ q.course }} {{forloop.counter}}"
                    id="{{q.option2}}" value="Option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="option2">
                    {{q.option2}}
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="form-check mx-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ q.course }} {{forloop.counter}}"
                    id="{{q.option3}}" value="Option3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="option3">
                    {{q.option3}}
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="form-check mx-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ q.course }} {{forloop.counter}}"
                    id="{{q.option4}}" value="Option4">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="option4">
                    {{q.option4}}
                </label>
            </div><br><br>
            {% endfor %}
            <br><br><br>
            <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <footer class="py-3 my-4">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url 'home page' %}" class="nav-link px-2 text-body-secondary">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-center text-body-secondary">© Made By : <a
                    href="https://www.instagram.com/adiviki_p?igshid=OGQ5ZDc2ODk2ZA==">Adityavikram </a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script>


        function saveAns() {

            var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if (ele[i].type = "radio") {
                    if (ele[i].checked) {
                        setCookie(ele[i].name, ele[i].value, 3)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }

    </script>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the **views.py** function for the same:

```
def start_exam10 (response):
    # course=QMODEL.course.objects.get.all()
    questions=QMODEL.objects.all().filter(standard = '10th')
    timelimit = 50
    class10topics = ['uniserv', 'technical', 'health','commerce','arts','agri']
    return render (response ,"main/testpage10.html", {'questions':questions,'time_limit': timelimit } )
```

and here is the **url.py** file:

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns =[
    path("", views.homepage, name = "home page"),
    path ("class10.html/" , views.class10 , name = "Class 10th"),
    path ("class12.html/", views.class12, name ="class 12"),
    path ("class10.html/testlanding.html/", views.validating_users, name ="pre test infofor 10"),
    # path ("class12.html/testlanding.html/", views.validating_users, name ="pre test infofor 12"),
    path ("class10.html/testlanding.html/testinstruction.html/", views.test_instruction, name ="pre test info"),
    path ("class12.html/testlanding.html/testinstruction.html/", views.test_instruction, name ="pre test info"),
    path ("testpage10.html", views.start_exam10, name ="test_page10"),
    path ("testpage12.html", views.start_exam12, name ="test_page12"),
    path ("testresult.html", views.end_exam, name ="test_complete"),
    path ("testpage.html", views.testing_csrf, name ="testing_error"),
    #path ("testing_csrf_result.html", views.testing_csrf, name ="result of csrf"),

]
```

I have also added the following after reading online :

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/testpage10.html']
```